# Is there a "standard" way to develop an app like this?

Tags: ios, xcode

So I have just started developing iPhone apps and at this point I could use some direction as to the best way to accomplish a project I want to start on. Since I'm new I don't know the pros and cons of doing the same thing different ways.

In a nutshell, I'm trying to make a basic app that is driven by user content. An example would be a commenting system. Maybe my app has a story and user can comment on it. All this information (the story, the comments, the username etc) would be stored in a MySQL database on my server.

Is it normal to just develop my app in html/css/php on my server with the dimensions of an iPhone screen and just use a web view? I feel like it would be easier to do that than to do it all in objective C, though i've never really gotten my hands dirty making apps before.

Thoughts from people more experienced than me would be appreciated! Is Webview suitable to creating apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I say:

You can do the whole web thing with platforms like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), and it might be easier, but you should use native code if:

- You want the app to look and feel like it was made for the platform
- You want to do anything computationally expensive
- You want to do non HTTP networking
- You want to interface with hardware (camera, accellorometer, etc.)
- You want to do anything very platform specific

Comment: @EricSmith: Sure. Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 4):

Please note that apps that are just a `UIWebView` displaying a webpage will most certainly be rejected from the App Store.

You will receive a message such as this:

> We found that the experience your app provides is not sufficiently different from a web browsing experience, as it would be by incorporating native iOS functionality.
>
> While your app content may differ from your web site or other existing sites, the experience it provides does not differ significantly from the general experience of using Safari, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> You may wish to provide convenient access to a web property for a select or niche group of users - and may enhance that experience with features such as Push Notifications. However, such apps do not include enough native iOS functionality to be appropriate for the App Store. As an alternative, you may wish to provide instructions to your users on how to create a Safari web clip to add to their iOS device Home Screen. Or, if you would like to share the app with a select group of users, we recommend the Ad Hoc distribution method. See the iOS Provisioning Portal for details on Ad Hoc Distribution.
>
> We encourage you to review your app concept and evaluate whether you can incorporate additional features to enhance the user experience.